# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: manager for class: Script1

Tags: maven, groovy, jenkins, hudson, hudson-plugins

I am trying to invoke Groovy inside Hudson (using groovy plugin) to get some properties for our build. But I am getting this exception:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: manager for class: Script1

I get this with the following line:

```
def buildNUmber = manager.build.number
```

This happens when I run as an inline command within Jenkins as well as using a script:

I tried the solution below, but it fails during the declaration itself (line two):

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setVariable("manager", manager);
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
shell.evaluate(new File("d:/dev/others/hudson/userContent/ScriptStuff.groovy").text);
```

The above is run using: Groovy command. And when I run the build it errors and complains about the line - `binding.setVariable("manager", manager);`

When I use the Groovy script file, then it complains about:

```
 def buildNumber = manager.build.number
```

Both errors are :

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: manager for class: Script1

Tried everything mentioned in this [thread](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Groovy-post-script-error-td3216762.html) as well:

I am using Hudson 2.2.1 and Groovy 2.1.3. What could be wrong?

Comment: I tired in the script console and it fails there with the same exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing some part of your code, but where do you define the manager? If that's the complete Groovy script, you're trying to bind a variable which isn't declared anything, so it isn't surprising that it fails.

Just define a manager it that's what you want, like:

```
def manager = "my manager" // probably not what you want
```

This should solve your current error.

Comment: Sorry I can't do that way, as the manager is a value that we should get from Hudson instance.

Comment: I understand, but it seems like you are trying to execute a Groovy script yourself, instead of using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin, based on the GroovyShell.execute() command.

Comment: Make sure you doing a "Post Build Action" and not a "Post Step"

Answer (score 20):

`manager` is provided by certain Groovy script plugins, but not all.  To make your script generic, use the Jenkins/Hudson API instead:

```
import hudson.model.*

def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
def buildNumber = build.number
...
```

Comment: Great! How do you get job name from build variable? I can see build contains job name and build number but don't know how to print it. Tried all kinds of combinations

Comment: Once you have build object you can do . . .  'jobname = build.getEnvVars()["JOB_NAME"]'   'workspace = build.getEnvVars()["WORKSPACE"]'

Answer (score 10):

Just in case it helps, if you are using the 'Execute System Groovy Script', you don't need to use the 'manager' variable. This worked for me -

```
def workspace = build.getEnvVars()["WORKSPACE"]
```

Comment: It helps. Thanks. '''def JOB_NAME = build.getEnvVars()["JOB_NAME"]''' then later in html use $JOB_NAME.

Comment: Thanks you, it helped me !

Comment: It was reasonably hard to find this helpful answer, so thank you!

Answer (score 10):

One of the reasons **groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:** is thrown when you are using a variable outside of its scope or you haven't defined that variable.