# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Not able to get the manager inside groovy system plugin

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-scriptler

I am trying to get the manager inside a groovy script and it is throwing me below exception.

I have import the hudson.model.* and also running in groovysystemscript instead of groovy script.
Still I am not able to access the manager class. If I run it as postbuild groovy script in console instead of file(file.groovy) it is working fine.

I do not think this is duplicate of [groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: manager for class: Script1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083995/groovy-lang-missingpropertyexception-no-such-property-manager-for-class-scrip)

```
    def out = {
    manager.listener.logger.println(it)
   }
```

The Stacktrace.

```
 FATAL: No such property: manager for class: Script1
 groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: manager for class: Script1
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
at      org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
 at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:97)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:650)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:636)
at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.perform(SystemGroovy.java:93)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:533)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that 'manager' is only available in "groovy postbuild plugin" and not in any groovy script.